How to Output a PDF that's gonna be treated as images on Kindle Publishing?
I've tried publishing a LaTeX PDF with Go (board game) diagrams in the past, but KDP's PDF converter simply butchers everything, and I was too lost at the time to keep trying. Later on, though, I found books like this one on Amazon Japan, in which the publisher somehow managed to make the whole book composed of screenshots basically, I believe, so KDP wouldn't change anything:

Mine is also composed of diagrams:

But KDP is butchering everything:

Is there a workaround here? Does a proper way of publishing LaTeX books on KDP exist?

You can convert your PDF to image PDF using Ghostscript. Something like rungs -o sample-images.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfimage32 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen sample_1.pdf should work.

That really helps, but I then accidentally might have found the answer: through Kindle Create, you can choose to edit your PDF into a fixed layout one (or comics).

This may be even better, as it ensures that Kindle will really support your file.

One option is, as @michal.h21 mentioned, to use Ghostscript to convert the PDF into an image PDF:
rungs -o sample-images.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfimage32 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen sample_1.pdf

But Kindle already seems to have a standard solution for this type of thing, that is Kindle Create.
You can use it to convert your book into a proper Kindle Reflowable, which is the standard book there, or a Fixed Layout (Print Replica), or a Comics Layout book, which will preserve the original layout. That's also probably what the Amazon JP book I mentioned is using as well.
That's even better than uploading a more or less proper PDF to Kindle Direct Publishing (KDP), because Kindle Create will export a .kpf file, which is what KDP expects, and what they will probably support the most and the longest.
